# Tmux <prefix>-x command just stopped working

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

tmux 2.1
OSX El Capitan 10.11.6
2015 Macbook Pro

All of sudden, the `<prefix>-x` command to close panes stopped working. I use it extremely often, and noticed immediately. I have no idea what could be wrong. It just doesn't do anything anymore. Just completely stopped.

I can tell that the prefix is working in general. I can still make new panes with `<prefix>-c`, I can still move to different panes with `<prefix>-{#}`. It seems like it's just this one command.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your tmux configuration; even today (version 2.7), `<prefix>-x` is still bound to `confirm-before -p "..." kill-pane` by default.

Comment: `tmux list-keys  | grep kill-pane` check if it's still in the key table